# Insert LaTeX between Beamer slides, using pandoc markdown

Tags: latex, pandoc, beamer

I'd like to insert some raw latex (in my case `\appendix`) between two frames in a beamer presentation.  Normally, any latex code in the markdown document is passed through into the final `.tex` document, but it is placed within the frame.

My input:

```
First Frame
===========

Some stuff

\appendix

Appendix Frame
==============

More stuff
```

Output:

```
\begin{frame}{First Frame}

Some stuff

\appendix

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Appendix Frame}

More stuff

\end{frame}
```

And my desired output is to have the `\appendix` come after the first `\end{frame}`.  Is there a way to explicitly end the frame environment?  Of course adding `\end{frame}` to the markdown file leaves me with two `\end{frame}` lines in the tex file.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @bodycountPP, I wasn't sure about that and decided to post here since there was more pandoc activity here. The question really is about pandoc more than tex.  If others agree with you I'll move it.